# Searching a data file: coding in python vs c++

Tags: c++, python, search

First off , this isn't a homework assignment!!! :p What I want to do is this:

Given a data file(be it text or numbers) saved on the desktop i.e., I want to be able to search that file and pull out only the data I want and print it to the screen. I may want to do other stuff with it but I have no idea what options there are.

Also, would python or c++ be more appropriate. I'm not familiar much with python and it's been years since I've picked up c++ but I've heard that python is more efficient and although this program's efficiency may or may not be a big deal I have heard python is much easier to understand.

Examples,Code, Templates(<-- would be awesome)

Thanks all!

Comment: If what you want is to search the data file, the right tools are "grep" and "vi". If want you want is to write programs, then either C++ or python are fine choices.

Comment: A couple examples of the potential data and the desired search results would let people know if e.g. regular expressions are suitable, or e.g. some approach that cross-references data across lines is needed.  Without, the answers may not be applicable to your actual needs.

Comment: I'm not sure what I want to be looking for but I'm thinking it's going to be a text file that is composed of Data = then #'s that I want to pull out and print to the screen or do something else with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit difficult to answer without knowing how you want to specify the data you want.

If you can specify the necessary data using regexes, Python will probably be about equally efficient, and a bit quicker to write -- but you may be able to do the job with something like grep even more easily.

If it'll take a lot more processing to figure out what data to display, Python *may* start to get quite a bit slower -- it can be quite fast as long as the Python part is mostly a fairly "thin" shell and most of the heavy lifting is done by various libraries. It can get quite a bit slower if you're doing serious/significant processing in Python itself.

If you write in in C++, you'll get more or less the opposite situation -- as long as you're *reasonably* careful, chances are pretty good that performance won't be an issue. The real question will be how much work it takes to produce what you want. Without knowing anything about what data you're looking for, how you want to display it, etc., it's nearly impossible to guess about that though.

edit based on comment: A pattern like `Data = ####` sounds like pretty much a classic case for a regular expression, for which grep will work just fine.

This is also something Python can probably do perfectly well, but if you did decide to do your own in C++, it could look something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
    if (argc < 2) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: searched <filename>\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::ifstream in(argv[1]);
    std::string line;
    std::regex pat("Data = [0-9]+");

    while (std::getline(line, in))
        if (std::regex_search(line, pat))
            std::cout << line << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

This assumes you're looking for the `Data = #` pattern happening somewhere in the line. If you want to only consider it a match if that's the *whole* line, change the `regex_search` to `regex_match` instead.

The other assumption is that you're using a relatively recent compiler that includes the standard regular expression classes. This is the case with VS 2010 and gcc 4.6 (if I recall correctly) but some older compilers may name it `std::tr1::regex` instead, and some that are older still won't have it at all.

Comment: Any code examples for something that basically says Data = some #'s I want it to search down a file till it comes to something similar to Data and then print the number out beside it or whatever

Comment: One other thing: I would like it to search a "file" from a different location. How does that work in c++ (assuming your more comfortable with that cause of your answer in c++)

Comment: @Tyler31: I've modified it to take a file name on the command line, so you'd do something like: "mysearcher d:\somedir\whatever\somethingelse\somefile.txt"

Answer (score 1):

C++ will be faster (maybe, if you write it well), but, it will be harder, but easier to start since you know it.

Python will take some time to get used to, and it will probably run a wee bit slower, but, will be easier (once you learn the language).

This is a very easy problem solved numerous times, so, what language you pick really doesn't matter.

If you like a GUI, then look at GUI libraries.

Answer (score -3):

Python will be much better for this task:

```
for line in file("path/to/file.txt", "rb"):
    print line
```

The equivalent C++ is much more involved.

Comment: Much more involved? `std::stream line; if (ifstream f("path/to/file.txt")) while (getline(f, line)) std::cout << line << '\n';` Big deal.  Anyway, the kind of searching needed is the potentially complex part here.